# How to get the number of process sharing a file by using mmap?

Tags: c++, mmap, fstat

Is there any way to get the number of process those are mapped to a particular file ?

Actually, I want to delete the file which is shared by multiple process when all processes are down. Is there any way to do that?

I tried with `fstat` function call to get the number of `hard links` but since after mapping I am closing the file so `stat.st_nlink` is always `0`.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: I am using Linux RedHat

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to create a pool of your `fork`. Then you can access to every file either hardlink,symb-link and so on via `struct  stat` , pleae see `man 2 stat`.

Because you want to find out relative between `PIDs` and files you need to `/proc` you need to : `/proc/PID/stat`

I think the following project easy your job:

http://brokestream.com/procstat.html

After saving all of files of your process in a `std::tuple`, you can down your process and then delete your files.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that full path to the mmap()-ed file is /dir1/dir2/my_file, you could create a daemon, which executes `lsof /dir1/dir2/my_file` in a loop, until it finds that no process has `my_file` opened.

Assuming the applications are your, and you can change the code, I would advise another approach. Have one application that starts before others (can even spawn other processes), and have this application create and delete the file.